# How can I set a different sender e-mail address from office 365?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I want to use a different sender e-mail address from office 365.
At the moment, I set a folder to receive certain e-mails in my mailbox.
From the new folder, I would like to send emails to people from not the main e-mail address that I usually use but a different one. How can I do that?

Your advice would be very much appreciated.

Comment: This is the way we used to have to do it: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/hot/2012/04/26/how-to-add-an-alias-to-an-office-365-account-and-how-to-set-up-outlook-to-send-email-messages-as-this-alias/. But it looks like you can use groups now: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/create-groups/allow-members-to-send-as-or-send-on-behalf-of-group?view=o365-worldwide. It’s possible they finally let you choose or type in an alias address in the from field as well now. But that has been the big limitation all along. Most O365 admins use shared mailboxes for a similar functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something called an **Alias** that you can use to send email to people and it will appear as if it has come from a different email address